# Error In Show And Edit Articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I have an error when I press show articles and when I press update articles when editing the article. I will show you the image and my code if you think it is not sufficient enough, asking will do just fine.

Image of the show error :
[image]

Image of the edit error :
[image]

my code :

edit.html.erb:

```
    <h1>Edit the existing article</h1>
    <% if @article.errors.any? %>
      <h2>The following errors are informing you that if you don't do these then 
      your articles will not be edited</h2>
       <ul>
         <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li> <%= msg %> </li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     <% end %>
       <%= form_for @article do |f| %>
       <p>
         <%= f.label :title %>
         <%= f.text_field:title %>
       </p>
      <p>
         <%= f.label :description  %>
          <%= f.text_area :description %>
       </p>
        <p>
         <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Back To The List Of Articles", articles_path  %>
```

show.html.erb:

```
    <h1>Showing selected articles</h1>

     <p>
         Title: <%= @article.title %>


       </p>
      <p>
          Description: <%= @article.description %>


    </p>

     <%= link_to "Back To The List Of Articles", articles_path  %>
     <%= link_to "Edit This Article", edit_articles_path(@article)  %>
```

articles_controller :

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
     def index

      @articles = Article.all

     end 
       def new
         @article = Article.new 
       end
    def edit 
         @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end 
     def update 
            @article = Article.find(params[:id])
            if @article.update 
                 flash[:notice] = "article was updated"
                 redirect_to(@article)
           else
                render 'edit'
            end 
     end 
       def create
         @article = Article.new(article_params)
          if @article.save
           flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
            redirect_to (@article)
          else
            render 'new'
           end 
         end
          def show
             @article = Article.find(params[:id])
         end 
         private 
         def article_params 
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
          end
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <h1>ARTICLES</h1>

      <table>

       <tr>

          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>


      </tr>
       </table>

           <% @articles.each do |article|   %>

    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Back To The List Of Articles", articles_path  %>
```

new.html.erb :

```
       <h1>Create an article</h1>
     <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <h2>The following errors are informing you that if you don't do these then 
     your articles will not be created</h2>
      <ul>
         <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li> <%= msg %> </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
     <%= form_for @article do |f| %>
       <p>
         <%= f.label :title %>
         <%= f.text_field:title %>
       </p>
        <p>
        <%= f.label :description  %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </p>
       <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
       </p>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Back To The List Of Articles", articles_path  %>
```

routes.rb :

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest 
priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'
resources :articles

root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'


  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: 
product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions 
automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do 
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: can you show your routes? And which is the link you click to show article? Can you post the full backtrace there?

Comment: yeah i will put in the question

Comment: I'm still not sure how you got your error with `#show`. Did you click the 'show' link on your index page?

Comment: yes I did that i also got confused when you asked me about the routes.rb

Comment: Not sure why you have your first error. Can you try to restart your server? And if you still have the error, can you show the full backtrace?

Comment: You have to pass `article_params` like this `if @article.update(article_params)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the URL you're visiting in the first error, but based on the error I would assume you accidentally went to http://devurl/article/edit <-- in your routes it will show the `show` route as `/article/#id`, so it tried to use "edit" as the id for the article, thus the `Couldn't find Article with id="edit"`.

On your second error, in your `update` method, you're calling `@article.update`, but the [ActiveRecord update method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) requires passing an explicit `id` and parameters to be updated. Try this..

```
def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if if @article.update(article_params) 
             flash[:notice] = "article was updated"
             redirect_to(@article)
       else
            render 'edit'
        end 
 end
```

- Edited to use correct update method. Thanks @t s

Comment: Or you can call like this `if @article.update(article_params)`

Comment: it is showing me the article after I edit it but when I update it is not updating it

Comment: @ts is correct. It was late. You should use the `@article.update(article_params)`. The way I originally posted it was just finding the article and resaving it without changing any fields. I edited the original answer to show the correct way